# Go GOTRACEBACK=crash with no core file

Tags: go, stack-trace, coredump, traceback

go version go1.8.3 darwin/amd64

```
ulimit -c unlimited
env GOTRACEBACK=crash ./testgotraceback.go
ls -al 
no core file generated.
```

#### `testgotraceback.go` source file

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func saferoutine(c chan bool) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println("Count:", i)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
    c <- true
}
func panicgoroutine(c chan bool) {
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    panic("Panic, omg ...")
    c <- true
}
func main() {
    c := make(chan bool, 2)
    go saferoutine(c)
    go panicgoroutine(c)
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        <-c
    }
}
```

I want to use core file to trace some error.But use the GOTRACEBACK=crash command,I find no core file.use golang1.7 as well. 
so ,what's the problem?thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting a core dump file to be created in the directory where you program is being run, you not only need to use `ulimit` and set `GOTRACEBACK` but also **change settings on your operating system to save `core` file in the current directory**.

Assuming you are using Linux, this is distribution-specific. You need to find relevant `sysfs` entry and save `core` value to it. For example, a core pattern `sysfs` entry on Fedora is `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` and to setup you OS to save core files in the current directory, you would need to execute:

```
echo core > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```